# How to work with TFS 2010 from VB6

Tags: vb6

I have installed latest

[Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6)

[Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 - ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=329)

But having issue with finding the way how VB6 works with TFS2010. There is no any menu that is referencing TFS in VB6 IDE. Could someone gave me a direction. Thanks

**Update:**

I have missed one thing, installing VSS 6.0d after installing VB6; It looks like MSSCCI is only replacing existing VSS menu in VB6 IDE. Now I have this menu available.

[image: vb6 tfs menu]

Comment: VB6 was obsolete a decade before TFS existed. Hence, no "Team" menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never get all of the features, as John has pointed out. This is due to the explorer not folding into a version of Visual Studio that old. To use the MSSCCI provider for check ins and check outs, try the suggestions in this blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2006/04/10/572826.aspx

NOTE: You will have to switch back if you are working on other types of projects, so keep this page bookmarked.

Comment: How you are doing check ins and check outs?

Comment: When I have used Visual Studio 6 with an older version, I was able to use the menu. But if this is not possible, make sure you have downloaded the actual explorer and you can then get access to source and check out. Then edit the file(s) and check in. A pain, but historically common with other non-MSSCCI source control systems, like Subversion, etc.